# Connecting MAAS to VMWare Workstation machines

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm trying to connect my MAAS version: 2.4.2 to my VMWare Workstation 15.0 so that it will retrieve the machines from VMWare Workstation. I have read earlier questions and answers and saw that the Workstation machines need to be in the 'Shared Folder' so I did that. I also enabled sharing in VMWare Workstation. I checked my firewall and network connection. I am able to telnet to my Workstation machine on port 443 and I get a connection, but when I try to add the "chassis" in MAAS it doesn't give me any response. When I try to edit the power configuration of one of the existing machines and add my credentials it gives me an SSL error:

[image]

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. I asked for a solution on the MAAS forums and you can try two things:

1. Try to import the SSL certificate yourself.
2. Add 'https+unverified' to the field VMWare API Protocol (optional).

The second solution fixed the problem for me and I can now power on/off the machines from MAAS. Super!

Comment: Excellent find mate, thank you! This helped me to connect to vSphere/vCenter